# Bluetooth Tethering Windows 10 & Nexus 5x

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, bluetooth

I am trying to setup bluetooth tethering between a Windows 10 Laptop and a (rooted) Nexus 5X Android device, running the latest 6.0.1 version of Android (update from March 2016).

I have managed to pair the two devices, install the Bluetooth network adapter, but I fail to connect the phone as an access point. When I click the "Connect Using..." on the device in the list, I can only find the "Direct connection" which does not do anything. From what I found online, I need to have a "Access Point" option in the dropdown. Also, the device shows in the properties -> Services screen only "Remote Control" and "SMS/MMS" as options. I would assume that there needs to be some kind of "Network" service?

Comment: Which Android version are you using?

Comment: @Spokey 6.0.1, updated above.

Comment: I could be that windows uses the wrong driver. What devices do you see in Device Manager? What about in Devices and Printers? You can also try uninstalling that device, it will then force windows to re-install it, hopefully with the right driver.